# Prevent Class From Being Externally Used In Typescript Definition File

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript definition file:

```
declare class Bar {

}

declare const exampleBar: Bar

declare function testBars(...bars: Array<Bar>): void
```

Is it possible to make it so the user cannot create any new instances of the `Bar` class, instead they can only use the `exampleBar` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a private constructor:

```
declare class Bar {
    private constructor();
}
```

If you are generating the declaration file from a TypeScript source file and you need to call the constructor (or define a subclass of `Bar`), ideally you'd be able to just mark the constructor `@internal` and use the `stripInternal` compiler option, but [that doesn't work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27455).  Your best option for now is probably to define a constant of `Bar` casted to a type with a public constructor and mark that constant `@internal`.

```
class Bar {
    private constructor() {}
}

/** @internal */
const BarConstructor = <{new(): Bar}>Bar;

const exampleBar: Bar = new BarConstructor();
```

In addition to doing the above, if you want to stop callers from manually creating object literals structurally compatible with `Bar`, then add a dummy private property to `Bar`.